# Angular 6 - Search text in Firebase realtime-database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, autocomplete, angular6, backend, angularfire

I use angular 6 , firebase realtime database and angularfire.

I can filter content from my realtime firebase database. However, I did manage to make it work by the function "starts with".

How can I modify my code to obtain a "querytext"?

Thank you for your help

Service.ts

```
getGeo(queryText:string) {return this.database.list('/EG', ref => ref 
  .orderByChild("nom") 
  .startAt(queryText) 
  .endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff")).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
return actions.map(a => {
const data = a.payload.val();
const key = a.payload.key;
return {key, ...data };
});
})); }
```